# Convert string percentage to double

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, double

I have a string percentage in an array that I'd like to convert to a double. Obviously I have to both remove the percentage and then do something along the lines of `[string doubleValue]`. What is the most efficient way of removing the %? The action is repeated often so the method must be somewhat resource conservative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your string begins with a valid text representation of a floating-point number (it can only contain whitespace at the beginning), you can call `doubleValue` and omit any preprocessing of the string.

```
NSLog(@"value: %f", [@"    95.5%" doubleValue]); // --> value: 95.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

If the percentage sign is always the last symbol, would `[string substringToIndex:string.length-1]` suffice?